# How can I execute two actions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to execute two actions.

It's a toggle for `#mobileJ` and `#botaojs` but they aren't executing at the same time; I would like to make both actions happen together.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#namala").click(function(){
    $("#mobileJ").toggle(function () {
      $("#botaojs").toggleClass("toggleclass");
    });            
  });
});
```

Comment: don't do the 2nd action in a callback.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, I don't believe it can do two things at the same time (although the time-difference between actions can be in the order of milliseconds)

Comment: can u prep a jsfiddle?

Comment: The first parameter that should be passed to `.toggle()` should be the duration over which your element will be toggled. Your `.toggle()` function currently returns `undefined` which jQuery will take as 0. Your `.toggleClass()` method is then executed (0 seconds later). TL;DR Although you are using `.toggle()` incorrectly, your code does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas for the cleanup edit, ([for the record, we saw it and were discussing it as well](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21722425#21722425))

Comment: @gunr: I'm glad; I was just skimming [meta] to see if we're meant to flag idiotic approvals (because that was *atrocious*). Sigh...it's the first time I've been actively irritated by someone's attempt to (presumably) 'help.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The callback function for `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) happens *after it's complete*, not at the same time.  In order for both to happen simultaneously (at least *observed* simultaneously, though there's likely some millisecond-delay), don't use the callback.  Just execute them both:

```
$("#mobileJ").toggle();
$("#botaojs").toggleClass("toggleclass");
```

Comment: @Phil: Beats me, but voting is anonymous by design and should never be taken personally, so it's no big deal.  Hopefully the OP is helped by this or other answers :)

Comment: haha, I know, I was just wondering if there was something technical I as missing that the down voter had found.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the second action in a callback

```
<!-- Script Jquery -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#namala").click(function(){
        $("#botaojs").toggleClass("toggleclass");
        $("#mobileJ").toggle();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As an aside, in response to your edit (reviewed here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7136477), might I suggest reading these articles: "[What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)" and "[Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)"